# Closing WebSocket connection

Tags: java, api, websocket, binance

I already have SDK with WS connection, but it has no method to close it. In documentation has been said:

```
 * @deprecated This method is no longer functional. Please use the returned {@link Closeable} from any of the other methods to close the web socket.
 
@Override
public void close() { }

private Closeable createNewWebSocket(String channel, BinanceApiWebSocketListener<?> listener) {
    String streamingUrl = String.format("%s/%s", BinanceApiConfig.getStreamApiBaseUrl(), channel);
    Request request = new Request.Builder().url(streamingUrl).build();
    final WebSocket webSocket = client.newWebSocket(request, listener);
    return () -> {
        final int code = 1000;
        listener.onClosing(webSocket, code, null);
        webSocket.close(code, null);
        listener.onClosed(webSocket, code, null);
    };
}
```

So, how can I write close function to close my connection? Or get this @link Closeable?
https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-java-api/blob/8d38e8e63c8bf125aff963bac0284961af0630e6/src/main/java/com/binance/api/client/impl/BinanceApiWebSocketClientImpl.java

Comment: The documentation says to use close(). I don't quite understand what that comment on the deprecated annotation actually means.

Comment: Link to documentation: https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-java-api#closing-web-sockets

Answer (score 1):

It seams to me that the method returns with the Closeable. And this is true for not just the createNewWebSocket(..)...

In the github readme they explain it this way:
https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-java-api#closing-web-sockets

```
Closable ws = client.onAggTradeEvent("ethbtc", someCallback);
// some time later...
ws.close();
```

So you should not close the `client`, but the called method's return-object (the `Closable ws`).

In the the [link](https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-java-api/blob/8d38e8e63c8bf125aff963bac0284961af0630e6/src/main/java/com/binance/api/client/impl/BinanceApiWebSocketClientImpl.java) you posted, it looks like many methods return with such Closeables.

Comment: Closeable is just an interface and close() is an abstract method that is empty on the implementation override. How is that going to close anything?

Comment: Yes (and maybe I misinterpret something), but the empty implementation of `close()` is of the `client` and the `ws` has a non-empty implementation.

Comment: Yes, true, you're correct, my bad.